# Code terminates in sqlite_step loop when constructing an object

Tags: c++, oop, memory, while-loop, heap-memory

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *zErrMsg;
sqlite3_open("Resources/Database/database.db", &db);

/*
 * Loads tile objects.
 */
std::string selectTileObjects = "SELECT * FROM TILEOBJECTS;";
sqlite3_prepare(db, selectTileObjects.c_str(), selectTileObjects.length(),
        &stmt, &zErrMsg);
while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    unsigned int artId = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    bool animated = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);
    bool passable = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2);
    bool mountain = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 3);
    bool water = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 4);

    //TileObject newObject(artId, animated, passable, mountain, water);
    //tileObjects.push_back(newObject);
}
```

The issue with this code seems unrelated to using the SQLite wrapper as when debugging even a "while (TRUE)" alongside saving the value of sqlite3_step(stmt) which always correctly results in a SQLITE_ROW untill it's finished causes a crash, the two commented out lines seem to cause this issue however the tile object constructor does not reveal anything useful:

```
TileObject::TileObject(const unsigned int artId, const bool animated, const bool passable,
        const bool mountain, const bool water) noexcept :
        artId(artId), animated(animated), passable(passable), mountain(
                mountain), water(water) {
}
```

Database opened successfully, all the variables are loaded correctly, constructor does not have anything that could cause issues so is there something blatantly wrong I'm overlooking?

- Tile objects is a static vector of TileObject class.
- The loop executes correctly once and terminates (Does not throw an error) on the start of the second loop. This occurs regardless of the condition.

-If I changed the tileObjects to a vector of TileObject pointers the code works fine however if I attempt to create a TileObject pointer and dereference it when pushing it into the vector it causes the same termination after the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was unrelated as expected when objects are created on the heap after they are finished in use the destructor is called and if you execute "delete this" without allocating memory on stack will result in termination.